# Simplifying find operation on vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

I'm using a vector for several arrays in my code due to the requirement of random access to the individual elements of the array. Some user GUI operations require searching through the array (but not enough to warrant the use of `std::map`), so littered through the code is this:

```
if (std::find(array.begin(), array.end(), searchfor) != array.end()) { ... }
```

I'm thinking of a better and more easily readable way of doing this, perhaps creating a method so I can do something like `if (array_find(searchfor) != array.end())` or maybe even extending vector so I can do `if (array.find(searchfor) != array.end())`.

I'm not sure of the best way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: **Don't extend `vector`.** Extending means inheritance. Inheritance from a class without a virtual dtor is pure evil. And even if `vector` had a virtual dtor, you wouldn't want to subclass just to add a single, stateless operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use whatever you prefer. I believe doing a function is better though, it avoids the hassle of creating a new class and using it everywhere. Something like :

```
bool array_contains(searchFor)
{
    return std::find(array.begin(), array.end(), searchfor) != array.end();
}
```

Comment: You could even do it with `array_contains` as a templated function, which accepts any STL compatible container, and runs the search.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/index.html) worth a look. Basically you can get rid of begin/end calls as arguments, using collection reference instead.

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm/find.hpp>
...
if (boost::find(array, searchfor) != array.end()) { ... }
```

The advantage of this solution is that you still get iterator as a result, which often proves to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to re-write the entire Standard library to use ranges in cases where it's appropriate (like this one) and ensure that everyone that you work with also does this, then the first posted code is the best one.